# How can I notify store owners when stock levels are getting low?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, ecommerce

For a Craft Commerce site, the store owners wish to be notified automatically when a stock is starting to get low. Can this be achieved with a plugin, and if so, how?

Answer (score 3):

Just like Craft itself, Craft Commerce has lots of events you can have a plugin respond to. In this case, you'd want to write a plugin that waits for `commerce_orders.onOrderComplete` ([per documentation](https://craftcommerce.com/docs/events-reference#commerce_orders.onordercomplete)) that evaluates the stock levels and probably uses Craft's [Email Service](https://craftcms.com/classreference/services/EmailService) to fire off notifications to the store owners.

Here's some quick pseudocode:

```
<?php

namespace Craft;

class StockNotificationPlugin extends BasePlugin
{
    ...

    function init()
    {
        craft()->on('commerce_orders.onOrderComplete', function($event) 
        {
            // loop through the items in the order ($order->lineItems), 
            // checking the remaining stock ($item->purchasable->stock)
            // against your desired threshold, firing off notifications
            // if applicable
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much Matt, one is not a developer anymore though, front end is my bread and butter now. This needs a Control Panel interface, where you can set who gets the email notifications via the plugin, as set by the store owner - as it could be a few people that get the notifications - a stock warehouse as well for example and of course input fields for the actual stock level control per product. Yes, you could do that via a custom field/s, but it would be nice to have a configured plugin I feel.

Comment: @moondawg You might consider [posting a feature request](http://feedback.craftcms.com/forums/285221-feature-requests) for this, or see if you could hire a developer to build the plugin for you. (The Craft Slack account is crawling with friendly developers.)

Comment: Thanks Matt, Craft via Twitter said they could help. Quite happy to pay then for this to be in the 'core'.

Comment: @moondawg Kudos to you. Appreciate it when the industry pays for new core features! Well done

Comment: In Norwegian "Matt stein" means dim rock :D

Comment: @Wobee Ha! I can work with low expectations. Thanks for the warning! ;)

Answer (score 3):

We have created an working example plugin that can notify users by email when the stock of a variant drops below a defined threshold.

https://github.com/pixelandtonic/CommerceStockNotifier